# I can change tint colour on UIButton but not UIImage

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, uiimageview

I am playing around with tint colours on a `UIImage` and a `UIButton`.

On the `UIButton` (when the button type is set to System), I am able to set the tint colour of the  `UIButton` in Xcode by going to Attributes Inspector -> View -> Tint

On `UIImageView`, I have set the same image, but when I go to the Attributes Inspector -> View -> Tint, the colour of the image does not change.

Why is the behaviour like this ? and how do I fix it ?

I am using iOS 7 and Xcode 5.1.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your image's rendering mode needs to be set to template and not original. To do this, you can call the `-[UIImage imageWithRenderingMode:]` method on your image and pass in `UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate`, then set your image view's image to the resulting image:

```
yourImageView.image = [yourImage imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];
```

Or, in Swift:

```
yourImageView.image = yourImage.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysTemplate)
```